# MacBook Pro (17-inch, Mid 2010) screen displaying low number of colors

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My 17-inch, Mid 2010 MacBook Pro's screen now displays a limited number of colors, kind of "fuzzy". [See this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXLhd.jpg)

I search on the internet but I could not find a case similar to mine. Not search on which keywords to use to describe the issue, though.

Does anyone knows this? Is it fixable?

Comment: To test if it is your screen or the general graphics problem, if you have a cable connect it to external monitor or a TV. Also, start in Safe mode to test.

Comment: External display : working fine. Safe mode : same issue. I tried to reset the NVRAM, but it broke the system (couldn't boot anymore, and had to restore through recovery) and did not fix the screen issue.

Comment: Well it is not your GPU :) now lets see what it says in the About this Mac- Color LCD. It might be the internal cable (which is not easy to access. Also open the ColorSyncUtility app in your Utility folder and check for what profile is it using, or try changing it to another color profile. If you are replying to me use the @Buscar so I will be notified.

Answer (score 1):

As I see the screenshot, the colors on that display are inverted.

Try unchecking `Settings > Accessibility > Display > Invert colors`

Also take a look at the **Display contrast** and the **Increase contrast** options.

Here is a screenshot of the default settings: 
[image]

Comment: I have the same settings here.

Comment: Then it seems to be a hardware issue. Check the cable between the Logic board and the Display itself, also you may check if it's the Video chip.